# How to put an array in array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have been going over this issue with numpy for a while and cant figure out if there is a intuitive way of converting the shape of array while maintaining larger shape of the data.

The shape of data (numpy array) I have is

**(366,   17,   30,  144)

(time, level, lat, lon)**

The result I would like to get is

**(366,   17,   ( X,  Y )  )

(time, level, (NewLat, NewLon))**

X and Y are converted coordinates so each coordinate has different values, not like gridded data.

I have tried

```
def DataConversion():

    CompressedDatasetGPH = [] # Create an empty list for output dataset list
    
    # Loops for calling every point
    for i in range(len(lat)):
        for j in range(len(lon)):            
            Latitude = lat[i]
            Longitude = lon[j]
        
            ConvertedCoordinates = CoordinateConversion(Latitude,Longitude) # shape: (4, )
            LocationSpecifiedValues = hgt[:,:,i,j] # hgt(366,17)
        
            # Try to append the coordinate array in hgt(366, 17) as hgt(366, 17, (2,1))
            MergedArray = np.append(LocationSpecifiedValues, ArrayedCoordinates[:])
            CompressedDatasetGPH = np.append(CompressedDatasetGPH, MergedArray)
             

    return CompressedDatasetGPH

def CoordinateConversion(X,Y):
    ConvertedLatLon = np.squeeze(polar_lonlat_to_xy(X, Y, true_scale_lat, re, e, hemisphere))
    return ConvertedLatLon
```

But using np.append, np.stack, np.insert functions give me errors.
Thank you for any comments and advice.

Example:

```
ConvertedDataset = DataConversion()
print(ConvertedDataset.shape)
>>(124480,)
```

Comment: This is a "don't"! You are trying to create an array of arrays with different types. You can do it with numpy using object as the type of the array. But probably it'll be pretty slow for a numpy array.

Comment: @simre Thank you for the comment! I thought the type of  all the array in the functions are numpy.ndarray but do you mean I am using a mixture of arrays with different types?

Comment: I just looked it again. Can you add the error message to the post? Maybe it won't be different type but different dimensions. Please add any info to the post you can. Also a minimal reproducible example if possible. Just with some random data to be able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @simre I think error messages are gone after changing append function but the shape of the output is flattened as (124480,) not like (366, 17, 2, 10).. (example takes only 2 lats and 10 lons)

Comment: Repeat after me: "I will not use `np.append` without first reading the docs (and understanding them)!"  The flattened result should be obvious from the docs.  On further thought, shorten that to **I will not use `np.append`** (it is inefficeint even when it works).

Comment: It sort of sounds like you want an `(366, 17, n)` where the `n` dimension has some how be produced from the inner most (30, 144) grid - e.g. 30*144?  I assume the dtype is the same for both arrays - a numeric int or flaot.